# How to pull the latest image with Portainer?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I have a stack that is described by a docker-compose yaml file. I'm maintaining a single image with the tag "latest". This image is updated every day, again, with the same "latest" tag.

From Portainer/Docker perspective nothing would change (I guess) and it would assume no pull is needed.

Portainer does have a button "Pull and Redeploy" but I want to make this automatic.

How?

Comment: That is a very costly function to have from a portainer. 
`Re-pull image: If enabled, then when redeploy is triggered via the webhook or polling, if there's a newer image with the tag that you've specified (e.g. changeable development builds), it's pulled and redeployed. If you haven't specified a tag, or have specified 'latest' as the tag, then the image with the tag 'latest' is pulled and redeployed.`